# In Vaadin View classes should i use Controller classes or Service classes directly

Tags: java, spring, rest, vaadin, structure

I'm developing a mobile app and i have a Java Spring Boot as a backend and i have some REST endpoints. Also i have a web ui interface for some functionalities. I use http requests to the rest controllers from mobile device it's ok but in Vaadin View classes should i use Controller classes or Service classes directly.

I use service classes directly in the Vaadin Views but something seems not right for me but i couldnt figure out. [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x2NC.jpg)

Comment: You should use, what's best for your project. Makes using the HTTP-Endpoints easier to switch out or scale the Vaadin-Layer? Is the Vaadin and Mobile-App supposed to work very similar and does using the same interfaces enforce this? Using the services will remove intermediate steps and therefor should be a performance boost, but now the UI might dictate architecture.  And so on and so forth.  There are no silver bullets.